# is useMemo really helpful when results will be same?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

We have two variables, a =3, b =2, the addition will be 5. With the help of useMemo we can cache the result i.e. 5.

Now, let's change a =1, b=4, and the result will be the same 5. In this scene, will the result re-render or returns the cached result value?

I am trying to understand useMemo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for React, or for even Javascript to know that the output for your method when you the inputs are `1,4` will be same as the output when the inputs are `2,3`. To find out that the result of `f(1,4)` is same as result of `f(2,3)`, the result of `f(1,4)` should be available, which will only happen if `f(1,4)` is executed.

Also, here it is mentioned in the [docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#returns):

> During next renders, it will either return an already stored value
> from the last render (if the dependencies haven’t changed), or call
> calculateValue again, and return the result that calculateValue has
> returned.

As mentioned, as the dependencies change, the memoized function is called again.